# Split javascript key value pair

Tags: javascript

In Javsacript, How can I convert the following

```
[
    "1",
    {"Value1":"Active","Code":"25"},
    "2",
    {"Value1":"22","Code":"26"}
]
```

to:

```
[
    {"Id: 1", "Abbribute":"Value1", "AbbributeValue": "Active"}
    {"Id: 1", "Abbribute":"Code", "AbbributeValue": "25"}
    {"Id: 2", "Abbribute":"Value1", "AbbributeValue": "22"}
    {"Id: 2", "Abbribute":"Code", "AbbributeValue": "26"}
]
```

Thanks you

Comment: Your second array is invalid. You need comma's after each entry except the last one.

Comment: What's an `abbribute`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple loop will do:

```
var data = […]; // your object

for(var result=[], i=0; i<data.length; i+=2)
    for(var p in data[i+1])
        result.push({Id:data[i], Abbribute:p, AbbributeValue:data[i+1][p]});
return result;
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!  being a newbie, I just couldn't figure out how to break up the key value pair.